# How to search for a specific word within Long Text Area

Tags: soql

I am trying to look for a specific word within the records of Tasks (Field: Comments) using SOQL. I initially tried to search in a simpler Text field from EmailMessage, like this:

```
Select Id from EmailMessage where ParentId = '5003a034343ylPiJ' And Subject Like '_10D699999._a011ayjAKH%'
```

This resulted in 0 records. But when I search without `Subject Like '_10D699999._a011ayjAKH%'`, I could get 4 records. Am I missing something? Or, is there any other way I should be able to get the search working?

Update:

With @sfdcfox's suggestion, I was able to get the above query working. But when I do this:

```
Select Id from Task where WhatId = '5003a034343ylPiJ' And Description Like '%1434343%'
```

I am getting this error

> 'Description' can not be filtered in a query call

Comment: Use sosl instead soql

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample query for SOSL?

Comment: Is `_` supposed to be a wildcard?

Comment: @sfdcfox Actually it is part of the email reference: `ref:_10D699999._a011ayjAKH:ref` which is included in all the email transactions with a specific case.

Comment: As I am trying to debug: If there are any EmailMessages left orphaned without getting related to a case, I am trying to search for that specific `ref` word or any other common words from the Subject/Comments fields.

Comment: @AustinEvans Fair enough. LIKE needs `%` to indicate wildcards. So, if you wanted to use LIKE here, it'd be `LIKE '%_10D699999._a011ayjAKH%'`. Without the wildcard, it would only match if literally the first characters are `_10D...`.

Comment: Can you try this in developer console to verify:     FIND {*1434343*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Task (Id, description)

Comment: I'm late ...Derek answered the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (filtering on longtext, and general fulltext searching) is what SOSL exists for, so I'd prefer that over SOQL here.

The syntax is a bit different, and you'll get a `List<List<SObject>>` out of it, but it's not that bad.

```java
// "IN ALL FIELDS" can proceed the FIND clause, but as that's the default search mode, we
//   can omit it
List<List<SObject>> result = [FIND 'myTestText' 
    RETURNING EmailMessage(Id WHERE ParentId = :myBindVariable)];

List<EmailMessage> myEmailMessages = result[0];
```

Points to keep in mind:

- You can search multiple objects (just separate object names with a comma in the `RETURNING` clause)
- Fields returned for each object (what you would normally put in the `SELECT` clause of SOQL) are placed in the parenthesis after the object name
- You can use `WHERE` inside of each object to further filter

  - Semi-joins and anti-joins are still allowed
  - As are child-to-parent queries (e.g. Account.Parent.Name)
  - Filters in the WHERE clause(s) have the same limits as SOQL (i.e. can't filter a longtextarea)
- You can't direct SOSL to only search on a specific field, the search is across all text-ish type fields (text, textarea, longtextarea, email, phone)
- We only have 20 SOSL queries per transaction

Comment: Another benefit of SOSL - you can use SOSL to find stuff in Shield Platform Encryption encrypted fields, even with wildcards. You can't do that with SOQL.

Comment: Awesome! Great answer. Thanks Derek.